# Variables Values pairs in a Sheets Named Function

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Is it possible with the new Google Sheets Named Functions to specify a variable number of key value pairs, as it is natively with other functions like SUM().

My use case is along these lines to SUMANNOTATEDVALUES(1,"annotateone",2,"annotatetwo") etc.

I thought about using a LET(annotateone,1,annotatetwo,2,annotateone+annotatetwo) but I want to reduce the risk of the end part not being updated along with any other changes.